# Color link of the page you are on

Tags: html, css

I am trying to color the link in the menu of the page i am on.

I thought it war a:active but that only colors in while clicking it and holding the mousebutton.

How do i color the link of the page that i am currently on?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Share your code here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to put a class on it, such as `class='current'`, and use that in your CSS. :active doesn't mean current page.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3Aactive

"The :active CSS pseudo-class represents an element (such as a button) that is being activated by the user. When using a mouse, "activation" typically starts when the user presses down the primary mouse button and ends when it is released."

Answer (score 0):

You can't with Css selector. But on the server side (php, .net ...) you can add a `active` class on the current link in your view

Comment: For a small website you can just add the class manually to the links